# When I am trying to restart mt postfix and nagios the following messaged is displayed in the mail.log file

Tags: postfix, nagios3, sendmail

When i am trying to restart my postfix and nagios for sending a mail automatically about the status the foollowing message appears.

```
Status:Deffered.Connections will not be accepted from x.x.x.x because the ip is in spamhaus list[yahoo.dns.net]
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: your IP address  is in blacklisted list.  Probably you are using dynamic public IP than this will make sense.

Comment: What to do now? And even i deleted my ip from PBL blocked list still the message appears and the next day the ip is again block listed in PBL

Comment: How can i able to send the mails automatically @A.B.

Comment: you did not answer my question, private or public IP?

Comment: it's a public ip

Answer (score 0):

This is normal if you are using dynamic public IP. This is effort to block spamming used by ISP.

However if this is private IP then you need to contact the blacklist host site administrator to exclude you from the list or your ISP to help you out.

To check blacklist IP [Blacklist Checker](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx).

Comment: how can i overcome this issue and how the mails can be send?

Comment: No you cant, you are using public ip. It will get rotated.

Comment: i tried even using a private ip and the same message appeared.